# Complex css to only select first instance of an element

Tags: css

I need to be able to apply a width to a div but only if **any** of it's parents have a class of **grid**.

Obviously the child selector allows me to select an element if it's a direct child of the grid div:

```
.grid > .test {
    width: 300px;
}

<div class="grid">
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

I need a selector that allows me to select the .test div even if its not the direct child of grid:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="another">
        <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'd imagine that I could just use a bog-standard selector like:

```
.grid .test
```

Problem with this is that I only want to match the first instance of the .test div. The above selector matches all instances even if they're nested. Any subsequent div's with a class of test should be ignored.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="another">
        <div class="test">
            <div class="test"></div> <!-- this should be ignored somehow -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hs3G9/1/

Is there any way to do this with css or do I need to resort to JS?

Comment: Rather than excluding the child elements, what about simply applying a "reset" style to the children? i.e.
`.grid .test { width: 300px; }
.grid .test .test { width: auto; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t a way of excluding that inner `.test` element without JavaScript. If the two had been siblings, you could do something like:

```
.grid .test:first-of-type {}
```

**edit**: Right you are; you can cook something up with the [`:not` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot).

Comment: Yes, I thought as much. I can't gaurantee that they'll be siblings. I'll resport to jQuery I think

Comment: My grid is always contained in another element so *:not(.grid) > .grid {width: 300px;} works

Answer (score 0):

Using the `:first-child` selector in css should work.

So for you case:

```
<style>
  .grid .test:first-child {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
</style>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="another">
    <div class="test">
        <div class="test"></div> <!-- this should be ignored somehow -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably I didn't understand the question correctly.
But I still think this answers the question.

Comment: How can it possibly answer the question if you didn’t understand the question correctly? :)